# How to autoload codeigniter4 library once and access it every where in Controller, Model, View like in CI3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-4

In CI3 we make custom library and auto-load it in config/autoload.php then we able to use it everywhere in controller,model,view by simple $this->rules->status() where Rules is library in application/library folder

But unable to do the same thing in CI 4, is there any alternate available for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to load your own library you have to rely on namespaces and create a new object whenever you want to use this lib. Also be sure to check `app/Config/Autoload.php` file so your custom lib is known by the autoloader.
Since codeigniter 3 superobject has been removed you can't access it everywhere whenever you want. However you can load it into a view, a controller and a model and make your views, controllers and models extending it.

For example a lib named `FooLib` which is in `app/Librairies` will be :

```
namespace App\Libraries;  

  class FooLib {

    public function __construct() {
      // your constructor
    }

    // ...
    
   }
```

And if you want to call it in a Controller :

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Libraries\FooLib;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class FooController extends Controller {

    protected $lib;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->lib = new FooLib();
    }
}
```

And make sure to add it to the autoloader in `app/Config/Autoload.php` by modifing`$psr4` variable if your lib folder is outside of the app folder.

```
$psr4 = [
            'App'         => APPPATH,                // To ensure filters, etc still found,
            APP_NAMESPACE => APPPATH,                // For custom namespace
            'Config'      => APPPATH . 'Config',
            'Libraries'   => APPPATH . 'Libraries'   // Your custom librairies
        ];
```

Comment: Thankyou, its working fine for me but i have two question, first is i need to make object of library class in view and model again, because unable get to library properties in view right now by using `$this->lib->status();` and second without adding in autoload.php its working fine so why it need to add in autoload.php.

Comment: You're right it doesn't need to be added in the autoloader I guess because it's inside the app folder (It needs to be confirmed thought). Note that you have to add it if you create another folder away from the app folder.
And yes you have to instanciate your library object once in your controller (you can pass it to your view) and once in your model.

Comment: Correct, the first PSR line maps the entirety of the App namespace, which includes the subspace of App\Libraries